# Scala. Partial classes

Tags: scala

Is there any equivalents to C# partial classes in scala                                                ? I would like to depart my functionality with objects like this:

```
// file 1:
object MainClass {
    def addValue(value: AnyRef) = ???
}

// file 2:
partial object MainClass {
    addValue(1)
}

// file 3:
partial object MainClass {
    addValue(2)
}  

// file 4: initialize MainClass
MainClass.init()
```

How can i achive this functionality with scala ?

Comment: In C#, there is really just a couple of reasons to use partial classes: to separate compiler-generated code from user code (mainly in legacy WinForms applications) or C# code from XAML code (in WPF apps). Why do you need to separate your classes? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest you can do is to divide your functionality into traits, and divide those across separate files:

```
// file 1:
class MainClass extends Functionality1, Functionality2

// file 2:
trait Functionality1 {
  self: MainClass =>
}

// file 3:
trait Functionality2 {
  self: MainClass =>
}
```

Note that by using the self-type and setting it to `MainClass`, you ensure that each trait can reference all the members that will eventually be mixed into the `MainClass`.